# Is it possible to change a wpf button in VS with the click of another button?

Tags: wpf, button, colors

I'm not sure exactly what code I would need to provide here.

I have a xaml window with buttons. In another form, I have another button. Is it possible to have the form button change the background color of the other button?

Thank you.

```
<Button x:Name="_12" Content="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="109" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="50,1,0,0" Click="Button_Click" Background="#FF40EB1D"/>
```

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _12.Background = "red"; // This is just pseudo code for what I want. 
        }
```

Comment: The solution depends on where the other button is. Is it in the same Window/Page then your code should suffice, just call second button in some way and change it's Background value to that color, you can even pick color from resources. You can also use binding. Introduce a property on a VM or that Window and bind style trigger to it. If you need code, I can do it, just tell it you want the solution with binding, otherwise, your code should be fine.

Comment: As asked, the answer is yes. If these are different windows then their various controls are private members. You could expose a public method from the one containing _12 and that method could change values on any of it's controls. You could get a reference to that window out of application.current.windows pick the one of the specific type _12 is in and call that method. The body of which would look pretty much like that line of code you already have. Or you could use a mediator / aggregator to decouple the two and maybe then a private method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a xaml window with buttons. In another form, I have another
>   button. Is it possible to have the form button change the background
>   color of the other button?

If your **' xaml window with buttons'** is Windows and the  **'another form, I have another button'** is usercontrol. You can sue the following suggestion.

In your usercontrol, you can refer the following code to change the parent window's button background.

```
    BtnWindowsForm parentWindow = (BtnWindowsForm)Window.GetWindow(this);
        parentWindow.button.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

Also, you can use the code in Window Form button to change the usercontrol's button background.

```
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="BtnWindowsForm  Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <local:BtnUsercontrol x:Name="btnUsercontrol" Height="327"></local:BtnUsercontrol>

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //by the 'name' property directly.
        btnUsercontrol.buttonusercontrol.Background = Brushes.Blue;
    }
```

[image]

If you want to change another windows button background, you can change the buttonusercontrol.Background  by the 'name' property directly.

Comment: This is so ridiculously helpful. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes why not. WPF is a tricker's delight.

You can use a checkbox in place of First button. On Checked property you can change the color of other Button. Now that you want both of them to look like Buttons. Isnt it simple.
Just Re-style the Checkbox (ControlTemplate) to look like Button.

Fun part is that all of this can be done from within XAML and you don't need code behind.

Next you say that you want to control appearance changes across Froms. So that would be similar to a Theme builder. I would advise you read about DynamicResources and ResourceDictionaries.